# Getting wifi AP detailed information on Android

Tags: android, wifi, noise, rssi, dbm

i used a command "iwlist wlan0 scan" on android virtual terminal application and get some information on AP's specially the noise dbm. Information are available if the phone is rooted im using cyanogen mod.

is it possible on none rooted phones?

any sample implementation on android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is scanning the surrounding APs and look over the ScanResult that is retrieved. Unfortunately they decided to hide most of the information, so there's not much you can see. This is really troublesome when you want to work around APs information with a non-rooted device.

[ScanResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html)